How to increase the Drop-out voltage for plungers used in Solenoid valves?
I am working on solenoid valves where the plunger is a soft iron material. The solenoid coil I am using is 24V DC 18Watt coil specifically designed for this valve. I am trying to increase the drop out voltage of the plunger to more than 1V. This is to have a safety factor in the solenoid valve where leakage current is present and the solenoid will remain close under some amount of voltage(less than 1V). Currently, the drop-out voltage is sitting at anywhere from 0.15V to 0.25V. I am aware of a bit of residual magnetism in the valve materials which could be contributing to the decrease in drop out voltage. However, the initial drop-out voltage for the same valve was more than 0.5V, and upon cycling it through couple of times, it came down to 0.15V. Does anyone have any information on how the drop-out voltage can be increased? OR How to overcome the residual magnetism in soft iron cores?

try using AC ...

A series diode or two perhaps? That will increase the voltage needed to actuate as well as to release, though, which may not be what you want.

Such a low "drop-out" voltage vs the nominal 24v input makes me think sticky valve, not how to get the voltage lower.

Soft iron cores can retain some magnetism after being magnetized. Use an alternating magnetic field with decreasing amplitude to demagnetize the core.
